# UI Development/Framework Recommendation

Tags: jquery-ui, user-interface, javascript-framework, extjs

I waste a lot development time on UI related tasks. General things like navigation and forms layout really bog me down.

I have been researching various JavaScript Frameworks that can be used to UI design. I've looked at jQuery UI, MochaUI, Sencha (formerly Ext JS) and few others but they all seem to be lacking.

I would love to find something that really simplifies UI development.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

ExtJS,Dojotoolkit, jQuery UI really makes UI coding easier..
ExtJS even have their [designer application](http://www.sencha.com/products/designer/) to make UI development easy. What do you feel they are lacking?